# Getting strange error when fetching events more than a week

Tags: ios, events, calendar, fetch

I'm getting the following error when the predict is set to fetch events older than a week:

> 2014-02-18 22:48:04.540 SimpleEKDemo[5283:1803] Error loading timezone
>   data from file system. This is a serious problem. Calendar data is not
>   guaranteed to be accurate.

I'm using the SimpleEKDemo Project from Apple Developer site. I did modified the fetchEvents as follows:

```
// Fetch events 
- (NSMutableArray *)fetchEvents
{

    //Create the end date components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dateComponents.day = -7; //If set to -6 no error

    NSDate *startDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents
                                                                    toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                   options:0];
    dateComponents.day = 7;
    NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents
                                                                    toDate:startDate
                                                                   options:0];
    // We will only search the default calendar for our events
    NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.defaultCalendar];

    // Create the predicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate
                                                                      endDate:endDate
                                                                    calendars:calendarArray];

    // Fetch all events that match the predicate
    NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate]];

    return events;
}
```

The events are being fetched correctly. Any idea?